# Pause slideshow on body blur and restart it again

Tags: javascript

I have created an slideshow on my website with the code below:

```
intervalID_nextSlide = window.setInterval(function () { nextSlide(); }, 5000);
```

when user minimize his browser window or changes the tabs, and then come back again to my page, slide show goes wrong(for example it stops in bad position or goes very very fast!)

so I wanna pause the slide show on body blur by the code below:

```
<body onblur='javascript:window.clearInterval(intervalID_nextSlide);'>
```

now how could I detect that the user came back to my webpage?

It should be sth like this:

```
<body onfocus='javascript: startSlideShow();'/>
```

Comment: you really should use jquery for this.

Comment: Have you experimented with the above?

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend using jQuery (I'm guessing that you're already including it if you've built a slideshow or are using a third-party plugin) and unobtrusive event handlers.

```
window.intervalID_nextSlide = window.setInterval(function () { 
    nextSlide(); 
}, 5000);

$(window).on('blur', function () {
    window.clearInterval(intervalID_nextSlide);
}).on('focus', function () {
    startSlideShow();
});
```